# Can we connect to database of localsystem in a remote network?

Tags: linux, putty

i have access to a Linux system "**A**" with public I.P e.g(1.1.1.1). A oracle database system "**B**" with local I.P e.g(12.12.12.12) is present in the Local network of system"**A**". i can connect to the system "**B**" through Putty. I have a project in my system which needs to user the database of system "**B**". is there a way to tunnel the system "**B**" i.p to my system so that i can use it in my project? my system is windows.

Comment: how do you connect to "A"? putty?

Comment: i use port 22. i have credentials for both system "A" and "B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh/putty to create an SSH tunnel, this will allow you to connect to your localhost and have your packets tunneled to the host in your remote subnet.

You can find out how to do this [here](http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/).

Comment: 1 more thing Tim. is their a way to download the files from the server "B" to my system?

Comment: There are various ways to transfer files over SSH. On linux you can use scp, rsync or ssh + tar for example. Since you are on Windows I recommend you take a look at PSCP (a PuTTY SCP tool). You can find it on the PuTTY download page: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: And here's a howto: http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/system/security/ssh/introduction/putty/doc/Chapter5.html